# Cross-compiling in Linux Alpine targeting Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, alpine-linux

I have a virtual machine running Alpine Linux with gcc 8.2.0, and I would like to use it as a sandbox to compile programs to be installed on an Ubuntu machine. What is the procedure for doing so? I guess I will need to perform cross-compilation, but haven't found anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Ubuntu chroot with [`debootstrap`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=debootstrap), and compile your sources in the chroot. I doubt there is an easy way to cross-build directly from Alpine Linux.

It is also not clear why you would want to do this.  If you have packaged your sources for Debian/Ubuntu, you should use a VM for that operating system and one of the native build tools (such as `pbuilder` or `sbuild`) to build in clean build environments.

Comment: Hi, Florian. My main goal is to have a clean building environment so I don't have to mess up my main environment when compiling applications (mainly downloaded source code) with extraneous dependencies. For instance, when I built the Ardour DAW application, it ended up changing my original libcurl4-openssl-dev lib by libcurl4-gnutls-dev. I would like to have a way to keep an isolated build environment while being something small. Maybe the best option is to go for an Ubuntu VM anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, please use a VM and one of the build tools like `pbuilder` in it. It will give each build a fresh, well-defined environment.